# Stuck with Parenthesis in OOP Calculator(not using Eval)

Tags: javascript, eval, calculator

I'm creating an oop Calculator but I'm stuck with the parenthesis.
I found a simple function for the simple operator but I can't find any article that can help me to calculate a string that contains parenthesis.

this the function I found :

```
function addbits(s) {
    return (s.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/[+\-]?([0-9\.]+)/g) || [])
        .reduce(function(sum, value) {
            return parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(value);
        });
}
```

I'm sorry i'm not really familiar with Javascript. 
if anyone is familiar with this problem and have a helping article or tips i will be glad.

thank you for your time and consideration

Comment: To deal with parenthesised expressions, you need a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser#Parser). A regular expression won't be enough (except maybe as part of a rewrite system).

Comment: @Bergi Thank you :) I'm currently looking for a parser to implement

Comment: Have you looked into [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html)?

Answer (score 0):

A regex can't do that.
You can use Polish Notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation